# How to just use "new" for a pointer of which type is int[3]?

Tags: c++

I know that we can use "new" to allocate one object or allocate an array. So how do I just new one object for an int array like below shows ? I can't think out of such way like new an int number for an array.

[image]

Maybe `int (*p)[3] = new int[1][3]；` also have same result as just allocate an array. But I want to know whether there is another way.

Comment: I would recommend using a `struct` so you could give the variables useful names instead of trying to remember what 0, 1, and 2 mean all the time. `struct point ( int x, y, z };`

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with my statement. You don't seem to understand what I mean. I want to know how to use new and only apply for an array size, similar to the other two methods.

Comment: For arrays where you only know the size at runtime, have a look at std::vector. And I think we understand what you mean, we just don't think it is the best option.

Comment: Quite frankly I have never used in 20 years this construction. Every time I come across a need of allocating an array I used a std::vector<T>.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It's a good advice to use vector<T> in practice. In fact,  I just want to understand the grammar about "new". As shown on my table, you can use "new" to allocate an object for `int*` and `int**` . But it doesn't work for an array pointer like `int(*)[3]`.  So I just would like to know whether there are some untouched grammars.

Comment: @LoveAndShare - Perhaps the "answer" to your question is that nobody ever does that. In the unlikely event that I need an `int[3]` I would go for `int* p = new int[3]`. If keeping the size is important, I would instead use an `array<int, 3>` or a `std::vector`. Or have the ints as part of a `struct 3D_coords`. But never used a separate, dynamically allocated, fixed-size array with the size as part of the type. :-)

Comment: I think the problem lies with new int[3][3] on the right column, which is a 2-dimensional array. It should be in a third column instead of being in a separate row. You cannot expect a 'type specifier without an array' (for the bottom left cell) to allocate three ints. (But you could try structs, typedef, etc. as cheap workarounds)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get what you wanna asked, but in the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Explanation), there is

> The new-expression returns a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, if an array of objects was constructed, "a pointer to the initial element of the array".

Thus, `new int[1][3]` return a pointer point to the initial element of the array, which means the type is `int[3]`. So you can use it to initialize the pointer `int(*p)[3]`, which type is `int(*)[3]`

I think it may help you.

Comment: As shown on my table, you can use "new" to allocate an object  or allocate an array for `int*` and `int**` . But it doesn't work for an array pointer like `int(*)[3]`. You can allocate an array as you show `new int[1][3]`. But You can't allocate one object like two other type pointers ( more specifically, I don't find the way).

Comment: Did you mean something like `int(**p)[3] = new (int(*)[3]);` ?